# javascript onclick time function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this in my markup : `onClick="parent.location='http://google.com'"`.
So, my question is how can I add a time event( after 1 second for example to open that link) also on that markup without making a script for that. 
Thanks!

Comment: By calling `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { parent.location = 'http://google.com'; }, 1000)"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { parent.location='http://google.com' }, 1000);"
```

where 1000 is 1000 ms or 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="setTimeout(function(){parent.location='http://google.com'}, 1000"
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout for more info on setTimeout(func,delayInMilliseconds) !